# Изучаю GO, дали что то типо задания: написать простой сервер, который возвращает JSON по запросу

Tags: golang

http://localhost:8080/je/b2
Как создать простой сервер и вывести что-то в браузер (типо хело ворлд) знаю, а вот что делать с JSON без понятия.... Help me, please.

Comment: 1) localhost на то и локальный хост, что только на самом компе и будет, т.е. ссылка на ваш сервер только у вас и будет работать. 2) гадать что у вас там за код и на чем сервер написан никто не будет, поэтому добавьте в вопрос код, нажав на `править`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первая же [ссылка](http://www.alexedwards.net/blog/golang-response-snippets) в гугле выдала такой наглядный пример. Теперь при обращении к серверу вам будет возвращаться JSON, который сможете распарсить как вам угодно

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "net/http"
)

type Profile struct {
  Name    string
  Hobbies []string
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", foo)
  http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}

func foo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  profile := Profile{"Alex", []string{"snowboarding", "programming"}}

  js, err := json.Marshal(profile)
  if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    return
  }

  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  w.Write(js)
}
```